# Vector field on $S^2$ whose integral curve is $\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, vector-fields

> **Explicitly** find a vector field $V$ on $S^2$ such that the curve $$\gamma(t) = \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \right)$$ is an integral curve of $V$.

How can we solve this in an easy way? The brute-force method of assuming that $$V = f_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + f_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + f_3 \frac{\partial}{\partial z} $$ and forcing the "integral curve condition" leads to the system of differential equations $$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}f_1(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \right) \\ \\
f_2(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \right) \\ \\
f_3(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \right)  
 \end{array}\right., $$ which seems just too difficult to solve.

**Edit:** based on a deleted comment, the curve is actually injective (because the first component function is injective). However, I don't know how to determine its inverse.

Comment: The problem just asks to find a vector field (such that $V=\dot{\gamma}$), which you just did

Comment: All you are left to do to make $V$ explicit is performing the time derivatives

Comment: For instance the curve $(e^t, e^t, e^t)$ is an integral curve of the vector field $V = x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, but there are no exponentials in the formula for $V$...

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture of the curve to see what vector fields might produce it?

Comment: I know that the curve "looks" dense on the sphere, but a picture is not an explicit formula of a vector field. Also, I don't see why looking at a picture "magically" gives me insight of a vector field...

Comment: Writing $\gamma = (\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3)$, for any $x\in (-1,1)$ (where $(-1,1)$ is the range of $\gamma_1$), it's not too hard to verify that the unique solution to $\gamma_1(t) = x$ is $t = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.  Thus, we have a map $\gamma^{-1}: Im(\gamma)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma^{-1}(x,y,z) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.  Can you then just say that $f_i$ along the image of $\gamma$ is $\gamma_i' \circ \gamma^{-1}$?  (Then you have to try to extend it to the rest of $S^2$....)

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to extend it to the rest of $S^2$ though...it seems too complicated.

Comment: I agree it's complicated - I didn't bother working out the formulas.  Does it extend to zero at the north and south poles?  If so, I think you can extend it to all of $S^2$ simply by rotating it around $S^2$.  More specifically, if you have it defined at $(x,y,z)$ and would like it defined at $(x,y',z')$ (same $x$-value), define $f(x,y',z') = f_1(x,z,y) \partial_x + \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta\\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}f_2(x,y,z)\partial_y\\ f_3(x,y,z) \partial_z\end{bmatrix}$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $y$ and $y'$ (or something like this.)

Comment: I think that there should be an easier way to do it though

Comment: I can definitely agree with that, and would love to see it.  (Incidentally, I don't get pinged by your comment unless you write @JasonDeVito somwhere in it.)

Comment: If you derive $\gamma$ then you will know $V$ along the image of $\gamma$. In the formula, you can multiply by some power of $\sqrt{1+t^2}$ to simplify the expression, i.e. scale it, and then express the rest as a function of $(x,y,z)$ for all $(x,y,z)$ or at least for those on the sphere. Then your $V$ will be scaling this field back by the same factor you did in the beginning. Just some hope probably for reducing computations.

Comment: Oh! Another idea is to work with the curve $\gamma^* = (t,cos t, sin t)$ on $R^3$. Your cure is projection of this curve onto $S^2$. And your $\gamma'$ is the derivative of the projection map $P: R^3 \to S^2$ applied to ${\gamma}^*;$. Now, extend $\tilde{V}$ defined along $\gamma^*$ to $R^3$ and then compose it with $Dp$ to get a filed on $S^2$.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli I think this is it, but how would you extend the vector field from $\gamma^*$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$? Can you detail it a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a result of a lengthy succession of trial and errors, loosely based on the idea that will follow.

Our $\gamma$ is the projection of the curve $\gamma^* = (t,\cos t, \sin t)$ onto $S^2$. Here projection is
$$ x \to \frac{x}{|x|} \ .$$

We have $\gamma^{*'}(t)=(1, - \sin t, \cos t)$. It easy (well, not so easy!.Initially I had $(1,-z,y)$ which just wouldn't work!) to guess that $\gamma^*$ is tangent to (integral curve to) $W(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},-z,y)$.

Focus on $W$ along $S^2$. We must project this $W$ onto $S^2$. For this, we must remove from $W$ its projection onto $(x,y,z)$-direction.

$$ W - proj_{x,y,z} W  = (\sqrt{y^2+z^2},-z,y) - ((\sqrt{y^2+z^2},-z,y)\cdot (x,y,z))(x,y,z) \ .$$
You can double-check to see that this is in fact perpendicular to $(x,y,z)$ vector.

**Guess**: $V= (\sqrt{y^2+z^2},-z,y) -x \sqrt{y^2+z^2}(x,y,z)$ on $S^2$ is the desired vector field.

Note that, as expected, this $V$ is tangent to $S^2$, because its dot with $(x,y,z)$ vector is zero (by construction.)

It remains to show that for any $t$, 
$$ V(\gamma(t)) = \gamma'(t) \ ?$$

And it is!

---

The original idea was to find a vector field that worked for $\gamma^*$ and the project that field via (the derivative of) the map $x \to \frac{x}{|x|}$ onto $S^2$. It turned out that some choices of $V^*$ working for $\gamma^*$ worked while others didn't. For instance $V=(1,-z,y)$ did not. I still wonder why this is so. It could be that in projecting out to $R^3$ and back to $S^2$ some key data is lost. But where and how? How could we have taken the guess work out of this solution?!

Comment: It doesn't work, because $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \right) = \frac{1}{(t^2+1)^{3/2}} $ and $V(\gamma(t)) = \left(\frac{1}{t^2+1}, \cdots \right)$. And the proposed scaling does not fix the problem, but I think it's almost correct.

Comment: I think I was not honest to my own strategy. I did not brute-force compute, but rather threw in optimism here and there.

Comment: Indeed, this is a nice solution, thank you! It seems that it was also essential that $V$ was a vector field on $S^2$, since it is not smooth on $\mathbb{R}^3$.